# Spring Security and PAM

Tags: java, spring, security, authentication, pam

I work with `Spring 3.1.1`.
I have PAM authentication and I want to use spring security to denied users to access files.

Normally Configuration is

```
  1.  <http auto-config="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/test*" access="ROLE_USER" />
     </http>

  2.  <authentication-manager>
      <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
        <user name="test" password="test" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        </user-service>
      </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
```

I do not want to use second section because I have MAP. I want to user first section.

Can I do this?
Can Anybody help me?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking but maybe this can be helpful https://github.com/kohsuke/libpam4j

Comment: how do you assign roles to your users ??? you need to define a custom authentication provider( e.g. use UserDetailService) to set role to users via PAM)

Answer (score 1):

you need to define a custom authentication provider to set role(s) to users via checking PAM. for example, following code define a unix PAM authentication:

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {
    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        String username = String.valueOf(authentication.getPrincipal());
        String password = String.valueOf(authentication.getCredentials());
        PAM pam;
        try {
            pam = new PAM(pamServiceName);
        } catch (PAMException e) {
            throw new AuthenticationServiceException("Could not initialize PAM.", e);
        }
        try {
            UnixUser user = pam.authenticate(username, password);
            return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user.getUserName(), authentication.getCredentials(), ROLE_USER);
        } catch (PAMException e) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("PAM authentication failed.", e);
        } finally {
            pam.dispose();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return authentication.equals(
          UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
    }
}
```

spring security configuration:

```
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider
      ref="customAuthenticationProvider" />
</authentication-manager>
```

more example can be found from : https://www.javatips.net/api/org.springframework.security.authentication.badcredentialsexception